# condition in SELECT in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a query that looks like this

```
SELECT customer, totalvolume
FROM orders 
WHERE deliverydate BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND CURDATE()
```

Is there any way to select totalvolume for specific date range and make it a separate column?
So for example, I already have totalvolume. I'd like to also add totalvolume for the previous month as a separate column (totalvolume where deliverydate BETWEEN '2020-08-01' AND '2020-08-31'). Is there a function for that?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use 2 table copies:

```
SELECT t1.customer, t1.totalvolume, t2.totalvolume previousvolume
FROM orders t1
LEFT JOIN orders t2 ON t1.customer = t2.customer
                   AND t1.deliverydate = t2.deliverydate + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
WHERE t1.deliverydate BETWEEN '2020-08-01' AND '2020-08-31';
```

Comment: thanks, the thing is that the query itself is a lot bigger. I just used a small example for the sake of simplicity. I was hoping I wouldn't have to join 2 queries for this task

Comment: @alexb If your MySQL version is 8+ then use CTE. If not then use 2 query copies this are identical precisely (till linebreaks and spaces amount) and look does the server is smart enough for to execute this subquery once. Or post REAL task, on real storage structures and expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with case/when construct in your columns and just expand your WHERE clause.  Sometimes I would do it by having a secondary @variables to simplify my clauses.  Something like

```
SELECT 
      o.customer, 
      sum( case when o.deliveryDate < @beginOfMonth 
                then o.TotalVolume else 0 end ) PriorMonthVolume,
      sum( case when o.deliveryDate >= @beginOfMonth 
                then o.TotalVolume else 0 end ) ThisMonthVolume,
      sum( o.totalvolume ) TwoMonthsVolume
   FROM 
      ( select @myToday := date(curdate()),
               @beginOfMonth := date_sub( @myToday, interval dayOfMonth( @myToday ) -1 day ),
               @beginLastMonth := date_sub( @beginOfMonth, interval 1 month ) ) SqlVars,      
      orders o
   WHERE 
      o.deliverydate >= @beginLastMonth
   group by 
      o.customer
```

To start, the "from" clause of the query alias "SqlVars" will dynamically create 3 variables and return a single row for that set.  With no JOIN condition, is always a 1:1 ratio for everything in the orders table.  Nice thing, you don't have to pre-declare variables and the @variables are available for the query.

By querying for all records on or after the beginning of the LAST month, you get all records for both months in question.  The sum( case/when ) can now use those variables as the demarcation point for the respective volume totals.

I know you mentioned this was a simplified query, but masking that might not be a perfect answer to what you need, but may help you look at it from a different querying perspective.

Comment: that's an interesting suggestion! I have never used these constructions before. Thank you for your suggestion, I'll definitely look into this!